# Reversing a string without using any libraries

Tags: arrays, string, function, pointers, reverse

Now I want to implement a function to "reverse" a given string. My idea was not to swap, rather I thought of declaring a new array in the implemented function to absorb the new string in its reversed state.
Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void reverseString( char string[  ], int size );

int main()
{
    char string[ 14 ] = "reverse me";
    printf( "The string is: %s\n", string );
    reverseString( string, 14 );
    return 0;
}

void reverseString( char string[  ], int size )
{
    int i, j;
    char newString[ size ];
    for( ( i = ( size ) ) & ( j = 0 ); ( i >= 0 ) && ( j < ( size ) ); i-- & j ++ )
    {
        newString[ j ] = string[ i ];
    }
    printf( "\nThe string reversed: %s\n", newString );
}
```

could anybody please help me to get the idea of reversing strings? Was I approaching the idea when looking at my code or what ?!

Answer (score 0):

```js
    function reverseString(string) {
        var splitedString = string.split("");
        var reverseArray = splitedString.reverse(); 
        var joinArray = reverseArray.join("");
       
        return joinArray;
    }
     
    var newString = reverseString("hello");
    
    console.log(newString);
```

Are you expecting something like this?

Comment: Dananjaya I'm using C my friend. I think this is another language! :)

Answer (score 0):

A String can be referred to as an array of characters with a null character '\0' at the end of it. If a string is "Banana", then actually the compiler treats it as "Banana\0". When dealing with strings in the program, you have to remember to append the null character to the string that you create.

Here is the working code for the same -

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char string[10] = "banana";
   char reverse[10];
   int start, end, length = 0;

   // Calculating string length - to be used when length is not already known

   /*while (string[length] != '\0')
      length++;*/

   //in this case

   length=10;

   end = length - 1;    /*this is done because indexing in arrays and strings starts 
                          at 0, not at 1...so string[0] gives first character of the 
                          string and string[size-1] gives the last character of the 
                          string*/

   for (start = 0; start < length; start++) 
   {
      reverse[start] = string[end];
      end--;
   }

   reverse[start] = '\0';   //here we add the null character to the end of the string

   printf("%s\n", reverse);

   return 0;
}
```

Looking at your code, your idea was correct. You just need to brush up some concepts like String indexing, Null character in strings etc.

The same thing can be done using library functions as well.

Comment: Prakash Bansal I need to know why you are calculating the length of the string, when you can know the size via the indexing that you've implemented yourself ??

Comment: I calculated the string length when I was taking user input, but after that I set the length to 10, and forgot to comment out that length calculation part :-D.. Also, I have edited the code now. You can check it out.